Ubuntu: unixODBC Driver Manager cannot find driver
I am trying to install ODBC on Ubuntu 24 for snowflake and I get
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/drivers/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so' : file not found
This file exists and the permissions are fine.
/etc/odbc.ini
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=cecil-dev.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=cecil-dev

/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Drivers]
SnowflakeDSIIDriver=Installed

[SnowflakeDSIIDriver]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
Description=Snowflake DSII
Driver=/drivers/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
DriverODBCVer=03.52
SQLLevel=1

Is there something that I am missing here?
